# Dividing the square root of $x$ by $x$. Is $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$ or $=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

So, we have:$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$$

When I worked this out, it gave me two different results: $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ , which is illogical.

First method I used: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{x}{x\times x}=\frac{1}{x}$

I got rid of square roots, by squaring the numerator, and augmented the denominator proportionally, squaring it, so that I don't change the ratio.

Second method I used: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x\times x}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

So, I just made it all a square root (Because: $\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}}{\sqrt[n]{b}}$), and in the end, $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

They can't be both correct, because, as an example:

Let $x=2$

$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}=0,5$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx{0,707}$

Hereupon, either  $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{2}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$  or  $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I guess the second one is correct, because we can start with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and work it out to be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ , but we can't start with $\frac{1}{2}$ and work it out to be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

But why is that? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Please help.

---

Notes:

- There's a similar question to this one ([Why is the square root of $x$ divided by $x$ equal to $1$ divided by the square root of $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227532/why-is-the-square-root-of-x-divided-by-x-equal-to-1-divided-by-the-square)), although its answer is surely connected to this question, it doesn't directly adress this issue. I wouldn't have asked if I could understand it just with the other answer.
- (Also, english isn't my native language, although I think I made a
  good job of explaining my issue, sorry if it wasn't clear)

---

Edit 2: Wow, stackexchange is awesome. My first question, but it got solved in minutes. Thanks to the people who answered and commented.

Comment: Your first method is simply wrong, $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \ne \frac{x}{x^2}$ .

Comment: Are $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{2^2}{3^2}=\frac{4}{9}$ the same number? If you are not sure, always try with real numbers.

Comment: "*First method I used... $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{x}{x^2}$*"  How did you do this?  Recall that $a$ is typically not equal to $a^2$.  You appear to have squared the expression on the left to get the expression on the right, but why should this have been legal to do?

Comment: " First method I used: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{x}{x\times x}=\frac{1}{x}$."
$$$$
$x=4$ has already been pointed out in the comments as a counter-example, which is correct of course.

For me it is easier to see that $x=100$ gives a counter-example because it is easy to see the number of zeros (that cancel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method one, squaring the numerator and denominator of a fraction does (generally) change the value. For example, starting with the fraction $\frac23$, squaring the numerator and denominator gives $\frac49$, which is not equal to the original fraction.

Comment: I see. As @Marc mentioned: Are $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{2^2}{3^2}=\frac{4}{9}$ the same number? If you are not sure, always try with real numbers.
________________________________________________________________________
I tried with $\frac{2}{4}$ and it worked, then I tried with $\frac{1}{2}$ and it didn't work. I just assumed hat ${1}{2}$ was the only exception.

Comment: If you square the top and bottom of $\frac24$, you get $\frac{4}{16}$ which is certainly not equal to $\frac24$.

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry, it seems it was a simple absurd mistake. I tried it with these fractions like this:$$\frac{1^2}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
And then:$$\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^2=\frac{4}{8}$$

In the second one, I just multiplied both by two and thought I was squaring, all based on the assumption that I you can find equivalent fractions by squaring.... gosh. Sorry.
Thanks a lot

Wow stackexchange is awesome.

Comment: In conclusion, when doing "testing with different numbers" in maths, always use **at least three** examples until you are convinced. Sometimes you need to do more than three to convince yourself of all cases, but sometimes after three cases you can spot a pattern and then have an idea for a correct proof, so it depends.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors it's best not to use division and instead multiply reciprocals. By this I mean we have $\frac1x = x^{-1}$ and $\sqrt{x} = x^\frac12,$ so $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = x^{-1}\cdot x^{\frac12} = x^{-\frac12} = \frac1{\sqrt{x}}$$

You've almost erroneously concluded that $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{x}{x^2}$. To see this substitute $y = \frac {\sqrt{x}}x$ and what you've written becomes $y=y^2$ which is false for almost all numbers, especially negative ones.

Comment: Thanks, just one thing: so $\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$? How?

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because I disagree with the premise. I don't find "using division" any more error-prone than multiplying reciprocals. If OP does, then yes he could avoid using division, but I think it would be better for him to address his division errors.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Division is not associative and it causes people problems all the time. It's why we use the existence of  inverses instead of adding subtraction or division in the field axioms. It's as common source of mistakes just like sign errors. I don't find division hard to use either but almost everyone in the world does. If you create opportunities for errors then people will make them.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Fair points. I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @AdamRubinson just 30 years of teaching. We created tables of logarithms and slide rules specifically because adding exponents is easier than multiplying. That's a lot of human history.

Comment: @CyclotomicField yes I changed my response because on second thought I do agree with you that students make more errors with fractions than indices.